# XML DB Login on APEX 4.2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

### The Issue With XML-DB and Apex:

I just finished the Oracle APEX installation (I'm using Oracle 11g Express Edition and APEX 4.02) i deinstalled the pre-existent version of APEX and installed the 4.20 one, and when I try to connect to the main admin page at:

```
 http://HOST:PORT/apex/apex_admin
```

I'm getting the annoying `XDB login` popup. I Installed it on many other Servers but I never get username and pwd for XDB asked.

### What I've Done So Far:

Searching on the web I found and tried this idea:

***XDB Server Configuration Change***

Tried running this command on the database server:

```
 EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(0);
```

Nothing happened, except that I got a 404 page error.

I'm really in need of your help guys...

Thanks in advance y'all!

Oracle Version: Oracle 11g EXPRESS EDITION (XE)

APEX Version: 4.02 (pre-installed)

### SOLUTIONS:

There are two solutions, depending on the case you are...

***NOTE: Run all the sql scripts connected with "sys as sysdba" to avoid any problem with permission.***

- You are on my case, deinstalled the pre-installed APEX (4.02) and want to install a brand new version:

  1. Move the existing "apex" dir (you can find it in your $Oracle_Home) to "apex_old" and unzip here the new "apex" directory.
  2. Launch `@apexins.sql APEX APEX TEMP /i/` to install Apex (use "APEX" as your tablespaces instead of the default "SYSAUX", to prevent any kinda conflict with the old one).
  3. Once done with the "apexins", run `@apex_epg_config.sql [_Directory you unzip Apex_]` to reload the image.
  4. If is not already, set the port for APEX launching `EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(xxxx);`

*xxxx = stands for the port you want to set, like the default 8080 or another like 7777, 8081, 8082, ecc... Just do **NOT** choose 1521 (listener port) or 0 (that disable APEX).*

Now you have reinstalled APEX and you should be able to access to the "INTERNAL" workspace.

- You only want to upgrade your pre-installed APEX version from 4.02 to the latest version:

  1. Move the existing "apex" dir (you can find it in your $Oracle_Home) to "apex_old". Then unzip here the new "apex" directory.
  2. Run `@apexins SYSAUX SYSAUX TEMP /i/` to launch the installation/update.
  3. Once finished, launch `@apxldimg.sql [_Directory you unzip apex_]` to reload the image, it will take a few minutes depending on the machine you are working on.

Now you should be able to access to your INTERNAL workspace.

Hope this could help anyone landing here, looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Troubleshooting a New Installation of Oracle Application Express (APEX)

**EDIT-The situation so far:** (In response to recently posted comments)

> The OP uninstalled the original instance of APEX using the script `apxremov.sql` which comes within the apex directory of the Oracle database installation.

This should be ok, provided that you have installed or re-installed some version of APEX in its place.  The set up is a more complicated when handling it this way, but with a little patience you should eventually have the same results.

### Re-Enable APEX's Broadcast Ports

The command you ran:

```
 EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETHTTPPORT(0);
```

Just closed access to Apex on your listener to all ports.  "0" is used for maintenance mode when upgrading to prevent any users from being connected during maintenance procedures.

The default if you had not changed it is: 8080

You can change it to anything (non-zero of course) by using the same command and selecting a value that doesn't collide with other active port assignments (such as 1521) etc.

In the future, if you don't know what port was assigned, the command:

```
SELECT DBMS_XDB.GETHTTPPORT FROM DUAL;
```

will jog your memory.

### Review the APEX System Configuration

I am referencing the configuration settings from my home system, which is working at this time. These are the specifications:

> Host OS: Windows Vista Home Basic
>   Database: Oracle XE (Express Edition) 11.2.0.2
>   Apex Installation: 4.20 (Original with XE install)

1. If you haven't done so in a while, restart your machine to see if any of the services restart properly.  Try connecting to Apex through a browser pointing to "localhost:xxxx"
2. Set your HTTP port to your chosen location.

...Just for comparison, accessing even a working install using the wrong path can get the error you've reported.  Such as:

```
    http://localhost:xxxx/some-other/path
```

**Accessing the Oracle Listener Using the Wrong Path**
[image: Incorrect APEX URL Path]

You'll have to check what option you have chosen with your server gateway (there is more than one).  Some options: Oracle HTTP Gateway (the most current; I'm using that one), mod/plsql Gateway, etc.  This may have an effect on your default, base pathway.

### Testing the Oracle Listener Services

1. Check your `listener.ora` file under ../server/network/admin/... this is the listener.ora file on a working instance (my home pc):

   ```
   SID_LIST_LISTENER =
     (SID_LIST =
     (SID_DESC =
        (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
        (PROGRAM = extproc)
        )
    (SID_DESC =
        (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
        (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
        (PROGRAM = extproc)
        ) 
    )

   LISTENER =
     (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
     (DESCRIPTION =
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
         (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Glenn-PC)(PORT = 1521))
         )
     )

   DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
   ```
2. There is also a command-line utility: `lsnrctl`, which has a few options for checking the status of your "listener". There appears to be three in my install.  One on port 1521 for the standard database access, one on port xxxx for what was defined for the XDB service, and another for something called "External Procs". If your settings look the same, lsnrctl has a command called "START" to get all the listener services running again.  That might be a good lead for you.

Onward.

Comment: Hey! First of all, Thanks for the explanations! Now.. I'm in need to understand how to disable that XDB login form that pups up when i go to the ".../apex/apex_admin" page...

Comment: Try putting a trailing slash after the last part of your url:  "http://yourhost:port/apex/apex_admin/" it makes a difference.  If that doesn't work, Also check http://yourhost:port/apex, which is the general access point for Apex users with app design permissions. The apex_admin account is accessible through here too.  Designate INTERNAL as the workspace.

Comment: I tried both of your hints but same thing.. i still getting the XDB login popup... ohh! forgot to say a thing.. i uninstalled the 4.0 one that install itself with 11g Express (with apxremov.sql) may it cause any problem? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just posted some additional comments at the end for you to narrow down the possibilities.  Check them out when you get a chance and let me know how it works out.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for all of your help and for the massive edit! Ahah I solved it in another way, when i will be in front of my PC i will add the solution adding it to the main questio, so other user can find it faster, thanks again for everything!

Comment: Added the solutions I was talking about! Thanks again for your time and help! :)

Comment: Thanks for moving up the comment about the INTERNAL workspace to the main post. (that's the master administrative account over ALL workspaces on an apex instance)  You got the right idea with the "upgrade" from the native 4.20 version.  Depending on how far back you're upgrading from, it really isn't an upgrade anymore.  You can tell because Apex installs in a new schema of its own.  Just be patient and export your important applications to a safe file-store frequently.